# Password Protecting Files with R

Tags: r, excel

I am using the openxlsx package to create a large number of excel files with conditional formatting. I need to apply a password to those files before sending them to my colleagues.

Currently, I am password protecting the files by using zip() and a for loop:

```
#set password
password <- paste0(agency_list[a])

#change working directory
setwd(paste0("C:/Users/Documents/Monthly Reports/Staging/",Sys.Date(),"/",agency_list[a]))

#loop through agency folder and zip all files inside with password
zip(paste0(,agency_list[a],"_Staff_Utilization_",format(Sys.Date(),'%Y_%m_%d'),".zip"), files=list.files(),flags = paste("--password", password))
```

The problem is sometimes thees files are being removed by my colleague's email anti virus software. Is there a way for me to protect these files as a batch instead of opening them individually while still using openxlsx to generate the files?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be directly about coding, but about what types of attachments can be sent through which email services; you might consider asking a similar question on superuser.com

Comment: One thing you could do is encrypt the file and change the file extension of the archive to ".txt" (or something arbitrary) and instruct the recipient to change the extension back and to decrypt with a password. 
This would most likely fool the filter into thinking its an innocuous file type (which of course in your situation it is)